# Include no Entity Framework a partir de um Enumerable

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Tenho as seguintes entidades:

```
public class Rota
{
    public Rota()
    {
        CidadesRotas = new List<CidadesRota>();
    }
    public int RotaId { get; set; }
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
    public string Observacao { get; set; }
    public bool Ativo { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CidadesRota> CidadesRotas { get; set; }

}

public class Cidade
{
    public Cidade()
    {
        CidadesRotas = new List<CidadesRota>();
    }
    public int CidadeId { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public virtual Estado Estado { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CidadesRota> CidadesRotas { get; set; }
}




public class CidadesRota
{
    public int CidadeId { get; set; }
    public int RotaId { get; set; }
    public bool Ativo { get; set; }
    public Cidade Cidade { get; set; }
    public Rota Rota { get; set; }
}
```

Quando eu realizo uma busca de uma rota por um Id, preciso que cada item da minha lista de CidadesRota venha preenchido com suas respectivas cidades.
Sei que da para usar o Include do Entity, mas não sei como usa-lo a partir de um item de uma lista.

No exemplo a seguir, me retorna uma rota com uma lista de cidadesRota:

```
var query = _context.Rota
            .Include(r => r.CidadesRotas)
            .Where(r => r.RotaId == RotaId);
```

Dúvida:
É possível trazer cada item da lista de cidadesRotas com suas respectivas cidades preenchida?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim! É possível! É só usar o ThenInclude:

```
var query = _context.Rota
        .Include(r => r.CidadesRotas)
            .ThenInclude(r => r.Cidade)
        .Where(r => r.RotaId == RotaId);
```

Pode ser que seu IntelliSense acuse algum problema, mas é um bug do IntelliSense, que pode ser acompanhado por aqui: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/6560

Pode tentar buildar que vai dar sucesso. :)

Comment: obrigado, vou testar...